# In Rust, what exactly are mutable and immutable borrows?

Tags: reference, rust, immutability, mutable, ownership

I'm stuck with the Rust concepts of **borrowing** and **mutable**:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Rectangle {
    height: u32,
    width: u32,
}

fn mut_area(rect_mut: &mut Rectangle) -> u32 {
    rect_mut.width /= 2;
    rect_mut.height * rect_mut.width
}

fn mut_string(s: &mut String) -> &str {
    s.push_str("!");
    let len = s.len();
    &s[0..len / 2]
}

fn main() {
    let mut rect = Rectangle {
        height: 50,
        width: 40,
    };
    println!("original rect: {:?}", rect);
    let a = mut_area(&mut rect);
    println!("area of rect: {}", a);
    println!("now rect: {:?}", rect);

    let mut s = String::from("helloworld");
    println!("original s: {}", s);
    let half = mut_string(&mut s);
    println!("half of the modified string: {}", half);
    println!("modified s: {}", s);
}
```

When I tried to compile it, the compiler told me:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `s` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> <anon>:32:32
   |
30 |     let half = mut_string(&mut s);
   |                                - mutable borrow occurs here
31 |     println!("half of the modified string: {}", half);
32 |     println!("modified s: {}", s);
   |                                ^ immutable borrow occurs here
33 | }
   | - mutable borrow ends here
```

I know there's a rule about mutable reference:

> you can only have one mutable reference to a particular piece of data in a particular scope.

But why can `rect` be borrowed but `s` cannot be? And how do I achieve what I want here - to print the modified string after the function call?

Comment: As of Dec. 2020, the code in this post compiles and works fine. Here is a [demonstration on the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=de74998ad44c0ec095f5b53bbfeb691d). This is probably because Rust's borrow checker has improved, and realized that you finished using the mutable borrow on `s` in `half` on line 31, so making another immutable borrow of `s` on line 32 is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you can print `a` after calling a function with a mutable reference to `rect` is that it returns a `u32` which is `Copy`able - there is no need to restrict further uses of `rect` because it is no longer borrowed after `mut_area` is called.

Your `mut_string`, on the other hand, returns a reference to its argument, so the mutable borrow remains in force as long as `half` is in scope. That's why you may not borrow `s` immutably for the purpose of `println!()`.

In order to achieve what you are after I would mutate `s` outside of the `mut_string` function (a slightly different name would be a good idea now) so there is no mutable borrow in force - its argument can be borrowed immutably instead:

```
fn mut_string(s: &str) -> &str {
    let len = s.len();
    &s[0..len / 2]
}

fn main() {
    let mut rect = Rectangle {
        height: 50,
        width: 40,
    };
    println!("original rect: {:?}", rect);
    let a = mut_area(&mut rect); // rect's mutable borrow expires after this assignment
    println!("area of rect: {}", a);
    println!("now rect: {:?}", rect);

    let mut s = String::from("helloworld");
    println!("original s: {}", s);
    s.push_str("!"); // s is mutated here
    let half = mut_string(&s); // s is borrowed immutably
    println!("half of the modified string: {}", half);
    println!("modified s: {}", s); // another immutable borrow of s
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So the returned `&str` is also a `&mut` to the string? And could I take `&mut` as some kind of "exclusive lock" to a variable that would be released when going out of scope?

Comment: Not exactly; the reference returned by the function is immutable, though the rest of your statement is correct - a mutable borrow is a sort of an exclusive lock on the borrowed object.

Comment: Got it. Guess I'll have to get used to these different concepts, but now I can see the basic idea is clear.